# Why is java.lang.String capitalized the way it is?

Tags: java, string, oop, naming-conventions

Why is the String class capitalized but java and lang are lowercase, another example would be System.out.println, println is a method so lowercase is expected, but why is out lowercase? Am I missing something or does someone not follow their own rules?

Comment: Because its the [Java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). Also, `out` in `System` is a public field.

Comment: What is `java`? What is `java.lang`? What is `java.lang.String`? What is `System`? What is `java.lang.System`? What is `System.out`? What is `PrintStream#println`?

Comment: packages are lowercase. classes are uppercase. System.out should be capitalized since it is `static final` but there are other `static final` fields in Java that are lower-case (Like `File.separator`).

Comment: @JaredRummler that's a somewhat tricky situation. They aren't really constants, but rather are just _write-protected_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class names have the first letter in Uppercase.  Package names are always in lower case as per naming conventions.

`java.lang` is the package name

`String` is the Class name

For the System.out.println() it breaks down as this

`System` is the class name, so the first letter is Uppercase

`out` is a public static field which is of the `PrintStream` class so it can be access directly.

`println()` is a method of the `PrintStream` class

Example of usage would be `System.out.println("Hello World");`

More information about this can be found in the documentation here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out

Comment: I thought java and out were nested classes. Someone said in the comment out is a public field, is this true or is it also a nested package?

Comment: as per documentation `out` is a public static field  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

Comment: please accept my answer if you feel I have properly answered your question.

Comment: Can you please update your answer to include the out part and maybe some of the source code of the out field if possible.

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.println()` here the whole thing is not a method name. Here only the `println()` is a method name and it is in lower case. `System` is the class name and `out` represent an standard object which I don't need to create implicitly.

More over `java.lang` is a package name and `String` is the class name. `java.lang.String` as a whole is not a class name, it's fully qualified class name.Each group in a package name always starts with lowercase.And it's customary in java to write the class and package name by this convention.

Answer (score 1):

"Naming conventions make programs more understandable by making them easier to read. They can also give information about the function of the identifier-for example, whether it's a constant, package, or class-which can be helpful in understanding the code."

Reference: [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

So, in your example "java.lang" is the package name and "String" is the class name which followed Java Naming Conventions.